# jQuery Mobile cache pages in order

Tags: caching, jquery-mobile

I have a list of a tags that are hidden. I tried using the data-prefetch attribute as described in the jquery mobile docs. The only problem is it fires off an ajax request for all of them at once and there is no garentee of the order that they get loaded in.

The ordering is very important in what pages are shown next via swipe.

So I decided to try and cache the links programatically via this bit of code.

```
var last_cache_page = false;

function cache_next_page(){
if(last_cache_page == false){
    var cache_link = $('.cache').first();
    last_cache_page = cache_link;
}
else{
    var cache_link = last_cache_page.nextAll('.cache');
    last_cache_page = cache_link;
}

//Start Caching any other pages that we want to swip to
$.mobile.loadPage(cache_link.attr('href'), {showLoadMsg: false});
}
```

So on $(document).on('pageshow') I call cache_next_page(). That part works fine the real problem is that when using $.mobile.loadPage no jquery mobile page related events fire once the first cached page is interested into the dom.

I have tried pageshow, pageinit and pageload but they only fire the first time the page is loaded. Now if I load the first page which starts the caching directly. That is to say with out visiting any other pages in the application it DOES trigger all the expected events such as pageload.

It is only when you start on page_1 and then go to page_2 (which has the code to start the cache) that it fails to have a pageload event triggered when the cached page is inserted into the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out there there is a .done on the object that is returned from .loadPage so I have modified my code as follows to allow it to cache my links in order.

```
var last_cache_page = false;

function start_caching(){
    if(last_cache_page == false){
        var cache_link = $('.cache').first();
        last_cache_page = cache_link;
    }
    else{
        var cache_link = last_cache_page.nextAll('.cache').first();
        last_cache_page = cache_link;
    }

    if(cache_link.length == 1){
        //Start Caching any other pages that we want to swipe to
        new_page = $.mobile.loadPage(cache_link.attr('href'), {showLoadMsg: false});
        new_page.done(function(){
            start_caching();
        });
    }
}
```